# CSRF expiring before form submitted

Tags: csrf, session-management

I have a very long web form that could take hours for people to complete. The problem with this is when people take too long the CSRF token expires before they're done and when they hit submit they get a 403 error.

To fix this issue I'm thinking of doing an AJAX request every hour to update the session and extend the token expiry. Are there any security concerns with doing this? Or are there any better ways of handling this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are absolutely security concerns with this; otherwise, the session timeout would be useless in the first place.

That said, there may be good reasons to disable session timeouts, but in this case, you can and should do so explicitly, and with full regard of all consequences.

To add to the solution: while I think it's already questionable to have a single form on a single web page that takes that long to fill out without saving in the meantime, with the risk of loosing the whole work when anything goes wrong (big usability issue), I think what you do want to achieve is prolonging the session (and thus the validity of the csrf token) by doing an ajax request every so often *when the user is still active*. So you should monitor if any form fields where changed (for example, within the last 5 minutes), and only then start the ajax request.

Comment: With a bit of re-wording, this is a fine answer on its own.

Comment: You are correct. I had missed in the question that the session would be extended as well. I added a note about that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set an independent expiry time for the CSRF token, the token needs to be unique and valid for the current user session, when the user session will expire the csrf token expires along with the session, and then you must generate a new token. This could be a simple solution.

Comment: So you're saying just extend the session?

Comment: I could just ping the server on input change. That would extend the session and solve the problem.

Comment: It's a horrible solution in my opinion :)

Comment: ok so what is your solution?

Comment: My solution is the one that I wrote in the answer, you must generate the new CSRF token only when the session-id of the client has been expired.

Comment: @jwerre if https is used on the site then there is no way for a malicious party to capture the CSRF token of a user. There should be no reason to expire the CSRF token until the session expires. *"In general, developers need only generate this token once for the current session. After initial generation of this token, the value is stored in the session and is utilized for each subsequent request until the session expires"* from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @d0nut How about the Encrypted Token Pattern from the same [OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) *"Once decrypted, the UserId and **timestamp** contained within the token are validated to ensure validity"*? Should a CSRF token have a timestamp value when used in conjunction with HTTPS?

Comment: @Code4R7 In that case, they need the timestamp. The encrypted token pattern for CSRF is like JWT for sessions. The encrypted token pattern makes a claim ("This csrf token is for <uid> and only before <timestamp>") and ideally is encrypted (AED preferably).

However, traditional CSRF tokens are tied to a session which already have an expiration associated with it. If you didn't timestamp the ETP CSRF token, then that csrf token would always be valid for a target user. It would only require 1 leak or enough brute forcing to permanently compromise the target. That's why it's timeboxed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me when user leaves the form for awhile with CSRF enabled for every request is to make a GET request in AJAX Success when request fails because token has expired. Then have a hidden field that continue to be updated with latest token and if at the time of making request it has expired you make a GET REQUEST to fetch latest TOKEN and then evoke click event on function that submits form which means the function has to be passed "this" or ID as part parameter.This makes the user not to realize the process of renewing token in the background

Answer (score -2):

*See [the answer by Nicolai Ehemann](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/119436/68355) for a more general answer. This answer assumes that the token is being refreshed without also lengthening the session.*

---

I see no problem with this. It is effectively the same as resetting the token when the user reloads the page. Assuming that you are using https and properly implement the ajax request and token generation, an attacker should still not know what the user token is.

The same risks apply as do when normally generating a CSRF token without ajax, because to the browser, it is basically doing the same job.